# complete action using alert during upgrade android application

Tags: android, upgrade

I want to upgrade my application when new version is coming. I used this [link](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/05/android-update-application.html) to do this .but the problem is when the application start download new version "complete action using" appears. what is the problem? should i define download manager in my application ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not disable that. That ChooserPicker will have to popup, if you want to do that.

Comment: @Hussein El Feky , what application should i pick to download my application?? I did not see any popup in any application when they want to upgrade.

Comment: You should use google play store to download your application. However, if you don't want to popup a ChooserPicker, you may want to make it automatic by making your application server side.

Comment: Hussein El Feky ,I upload my application new version on my webservice.i do not want to use google play store. my question is why this ChoosePicker apears?how can i force application to download without showing this dialog?